# Is it possible to serialize a JavaScript value to a string, and get the exact same value back?

Tags: javascript, serialization, local-storage

Is there any built-in way, or via a 3rd party library, that any JavaScript value can be serialized down to a string, and restored back to its original value? I'm talking about an equivalent to Ruby's `Marshal` class.

Something like `JSON.stringify` is *not* sufficient, as it won't preserve prototype chains, function definitions etc.

I have Googled pretty thoroughly without finding any mention of anything like this, positive or negative.

I want this in order to save application state in `localStorage` without having to define complicated serialize/unserialize logic for all my classes.

Comment: Short answer: Nope. Long answer: Maybe with a heck of a lot of `eval`-like hacks...

Comment: There is nothing built-in, no. Library recommendations are, of course, off-topic.

Comment: Probably not. You may have to create some sort of "rejuvenate" function which creates the objects from a particular state.

Comment: I just found a couple of libraries that claim to do this, [resurrect-js](https://github.com/skeeto/resurrect-js) and [HydrateJS](http://nanodeath.github.io/HydrateJS/). They appear to have some naming and style restrictions, so I'm not sure if they would work with classes defined in TypeScript, which is what I'm using.

Comment: Maybe you'd better to refactor your app in order to keep plain structure of the app state.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in that provides this functionality. You can build it by using a "replacer" function (and/or custom `toJSON` methods on your objects) with `JSON.stringify` and a "reviver" function via `JSON.parse`.